# Emulate R lang "?" command in shell (bash/zsh)?

Tags: r, shell

One helpful feature of R is being able to use "?<function>" to quickly look up functions, without having to type out "help("<function>")".

Is it possible to implement a similar behavior in shell (e.g. bash or zsh), using a non-reserved character?

That is, somecommand (no space) triggering "man somecommand"

Comment: Literal: `alias ?=man`, and then `? ls` (there is a space). The problem with your "no space" is that it completely defies the premise in shell scripts that blank-space delimited commands/arguments are ... blank-space delimited. If a full token is not recognized in and of itself ... it isn't recognized. The only exception I can think of is not a function or alias, it's the `~` homedir-shortcut, but that's about it.

Comment: It may be possible to override the `command_not_found_handle` function to handle this: see [3.7.2 Command Search and Execution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Search-and-Execution) in the manual.

Comment: However, since `?` is a glob special character, `?ls` _could_ be interpreted as a command named, say, `xls` in the current directory. The only way around this is to turn off globbing which clearly breaks things like `ls *.txt`

Comment: I was thinking of switching it to a character like Z. The main appeal of "?<>" is it's right next to the shift key. So a non-reserved character in a similar position, e.g. Z, might also be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, for bash

```sh
command_not_found_handle() {
    if [[ $1 != Z* ]]; then
        echo "$1: command not found" >&2
        return 127
    fi
    local cmd=${1#Z}
    case "$(type -t "$cmd")" in
        builtin|keyword) help "$cmd" ;;
        file) man "$cmd" ;;
        alias) alias "$cmd" ;;
        function) type "$cmd" ;;
        *) echo "$cmd: command not found" >&2; return 127 ;;
     esac
}
```

Comment: Thanks!. Works like a charm in bash. Might try and implement this in zsh later.